# How to query a postgresql database to determine it's cluster and version (and port)?

Tags: postgresql

I can quickly query the database name with `SELECT current_database();` but I've been searching for way to also query the cluster name and version with no luck - hoping someone can suggest a solution.

Comment: cannot retract a question after I've found an answer: select name || '=' || setting from pg_settings where name in ('port','cluster_name');

Comment: You could always self-answer (if your solution is materially different to the answers already posted) and accept your own answer if you feel it best suits your question. 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be

```
SELECT current_setting('cluster_name'), current_setting('server_version');
```

You can get all parameters that way. For automated processing, `server_version_num` is often better.

Comment: I mistakenly presumed you can only find settings that are defined in postgresql.conf and now know otherwise - I'm a little more powerful postgresql dev now thanks to @Laurenz Albe

Answer (score 4):

You can also query the pg_settings view

```
SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings WHERE name in ('cluster_name','server_version','port');
```

@Laurenz Albe suggests using current_setting() which makes it easier to select results in a single row